# TSQL: Get top 1 row from one of the tables in the JOIN

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is what I have:

```
drop table ttemp
create table ttemp(
col1 char(10),
col2 varchar(100))

INSERT INTO ttemp VALUES('101','shshsfhgs')
INSERT INTO ttemp VALUES('102','ertqehwrgs')
INSERT INTO ttemp VALUES('0102','witpipqcqp')
INSERT INTO ttemp VALUES('0103','retrtyhwqpp')


drop table #temp1
create table #temp1
(ref1 char(10),
 refdata varchar(100))

drop table #temp2
Create table #temp2
(ref1 char(10),
 refdata varchar(100))

insert into #temp1 values(101,'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
insert into #temp1 values(102,'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb')
insert into #temp1 values(103,'cccccccccccccc')

select * from #temp1

insert into #temp2
SELECT t1.col1, #temp1.refdata
FROM ttemp t1 
INNER JOIN #temp1 on t1.col1 = #temp1.ref1 OR t1.col1 = '0' + #temp1.ref1


select * from #temp2
```

What I would LIKE to have, is to get back only 1 row for each value in #temp1.
So if I have 102 in #temp1, and 102 in ttemp I should see that row. (NOT 0102)
If I have 103 in #temp1, but only 0103 in ttemp, then I should see that row (because there is no 103 in ttemp).
So I just want to prioritize the INNER JOIN: if t1.col1 = #temp1.ref1, then just use that one; not the t1.col1 = '0' + #temp1.ref1.

The SELECT from #temp2 shows this now:

```
ref1    refdata
101         aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
102         bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
0102        bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
0103        cccccccccccccc
```

And I want this:

```
ref1    refdata
101         aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
102         bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
0103        cccccccccccccc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it in 2 steps it is quite easy:

> 1. Insert high priority rows into the output table first
> 2. Insert low priority rows into the output table excluding any that are already
>      present from the first insert. (Achieved with a left join in this case)

```
create table ttemp( 
col1 char(10), 
col2 varchar(100)) 

INSERT INTO ttemp VALUES('101','shshsfhgs') 
INSERT INTO ttemp VALUES('102','ertqehwrgs') 
INSERT INTO ttemp VALUES('0102','witpipqcqp') 
INSERT INTO ttemp VALUES('0103','retrtyhwqpp') 

create table #temp1 
(ref1 char(10), 
 refdata varchar(100)) 

    Create table #temp2 
(ref1 char(10), 
 refdata varchar(100)) 

insert into #temp1 values(101,'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa') 
insert into #temp1 values(102,'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb') 
insert into #temp1 values(103,'cccccccccccccc') 

INSERT INTO #temp2
SELECT t1.col1, t.refdata
FROM ttemp t1
INNER JOIN #temp1 t on t1.col1 = t.ref1


INSERT INTO #temp2
SELECT t1.col1, t.refdata
FROM ttemp t1
INNER JOIN #temp1 t on t1.col1 = '0' + t.ref1
LEFT JOIN #temp2 t2 ON t.ref1 = t2.ref1
WHERE ISNULL(t2.ref1,0) = 0

SELECT * FROM #temp2

drop table ttemp 
drop table #temp1 
drop table #temp2
```

Results:

```
ref1    refdata 
101     aaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
102     bbbbbbbbbbbbbb 
0103    cccccccccccccc
```

Here's another way building on Joe Stefanelli's answer and altering it to produce the results you require:

```
SELECT t1.col1, COALESCE(ta.refdata,t.refdata ) [refdata]
FROM ttemp t1 
LEFT JOIN #temp1 t ON t1.col1 = t.ref1 
LEFT JOIN #temp1 ta ON t1.col1 = '0' + ta.ref1 AND ta.ref1 NOT IN (SELECT ref1 FROM ttemp INNER JOIN #temp1 ON col1 = ref1 )
WHERE ta.ref1 IS NOT NULL
OR t.ref1 IS NOT NULL
```

Results:

```
col1    refdata
101     aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
102     bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
0103    cccccccccccccc
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to "prioritize", you need to search the two conditions separately, then use a COALESCE to select only one result. You can repeat the COALESCE in the SELECT for as many columns as you need to return from table2.

```
SELECT t1.*, COALESCE(t2a.SomeColumn, t2b.SomeColumn)
    FROM table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN table2 t2a
            ON t1.col = t2a.col
        LEFT JOIN table2 t2b
            ON t1.col = '0' + t2b.col
    WHERE t2a.col IS NOT NULL
        OR t2b.col IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but it appears I am still getting 2 rows returned if I match on both accounts (both t1.col = t2.col and the t1.col = '0' + t2.col).

Comment: Check out the answer below at the end I have modified Joe's answer to give you what ou need.  Thanks to Joe for the method.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
on t1.col = t2.col 
OR (t1.col <> t2.col AND t1.col = '0' + t2.col)
```

Comment: In what way will the results of this differ from the results of the query in the question?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but it appears I am still getting 2 rows returned if I match on both accounts (both t1.col = t2.col and the t1.col = '0' + t2.col).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO #temp2 
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(t1.col1 AS int), #temp1.refdata 
FROM ttemp t1  
   INNER JOIN #temp1 on CAST(t1.col1 AS int) = #temp1.ref1
```

Always try to compare similar types without implicit casting.  It'll get you into less trouble.

Comment: Also, change the definition of #temp2 to match.  If #temp2.col1 really needs to be a char(10), do a double casting of t1.col1 (to int, then back to char(10).

Comment: Nevermind, I can see more clearly after your edit that the #temp1.ref1 values are char.  Your inserts into #temp1 are int.

Comment: Thanks so much!  But this does not match up my 103 to the 0103.  I need to match the number exactly, if possible, but if it does not match I need to match on '0' + the number (which these are all actually characters).